# WebCAPE vs AP Exams for domestic prep

Tags: multiple-languages, teaching, exams

I am going to be teaching a foreign language in some capacity and am not sure if I should teach to prep for the [WebCAPE exams](http://www.perpetualworks.com/webcape/overview) or [Advanced Placement exams](http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/courses/teachers_corner/index.html) from CollegeBoard.

I'll be following [**ACTFL** guidelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACTFL_Proficiency_Guidelines), but which exams are more often used by post-secondary institutions? Is there any data on this? Should I be teaching to prep for **both** WebCAPE and AP exams?